# Training custom dataset with translate model

Tags: tensorflow, translate

Running the model out of the box generates these files in the data dir :

```
ls
dev-v2.tgz                            newstest2013.en
giga-fren.release2.fixed.en           newstest2013.en.ids40000
giga-fren.release2.fixed.en.gz        newstest2013.fr
giga-fren.release2.fixed.en.ids40000  newstest2013.fr.ids40000
giga-fren.release2.fixed.fr           training-giga-fren.tar
giga-fren.release2.fixed.fr.gz        vocab40000.from
giga-fren.release2.fixed.fr.ids40000  vocab40000.to
```

Reading the src of translate.py :

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/translate.py

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("from_train_data", None, "Training data.")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("to_train_data", None, "Training data.")
```

To utilize my own training data I created dirs my-from-train-data & to-from-train-data and add my own training data to each of these dirs, training data is contained in the files mydata.from & mydata.to

```
my-to-train-data contains mydata.from
my-from-train-data contains mydata.to
```

I could not find documentation as to using own training data or what format it should take so I inferred this from the translate.py src and contents of data dir created when executing translate model out of the box.

Contents of mydata.from :

```
 Is this a question
```

Contents of mydata.to :

```
 Yes!
```

I then attempt to train the model using :

```
python translate.py --from_train_data my-from-train-data --to_train_data my-to-train-data
```

This returns with an error :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: my-from-train-data.ids40000
```

Appears I need to create file my-from-train-data.ids40000 , what should it's contents be ? Is there an example of how to train this model using custom data ?

Comment: Do you get any output from the script (other than the error)?

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler no, just the error. Have you trained this model using a custom dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blue-sky

Great question, training a model on your own data is way more fun than using the standard data. An example of what you could put in the terminal is:

`python translate.py --from_train_data mydatadir/to_translate.in --to_train_data mydatadir/to_translate.out --from_dev_data mydatadir/test_to_translate.in --to_dev_data mydatadir/test_to_translate.out --train_dir train_dir_model --data_dir mydatadir`

What goes wrong in your example is that you are not pointing to a file, but to a folder. from_train_data should always point to a plaintext file, whose rows should be aligned with those in the to_train_data file.

Also: as soon as you run this script with sensible data (more than one line ;) ), translate.py will generate your ids (40.000 if from_vocab_size and to_vocab_size are not set). Important to know is that this file is created in the folder specified by data_dir... if you do not specify one this means they are generated in /tmp (I prefer them at the same place as my data).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer to :

> Appears I need to create file my-from-train-data.ids40000 , what should it's contents be ? Is there an example of how to train this model using custom data ?

Yes, that's the vocab/ word-id file missing, which is generated when preparing to create the data.

Here is a tutorial from the [Tesnorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/).

quick over-view of the files and why you might be confused by the files outputted vs what to use:

- `python/ops/seq2seq.py`: >>   Library for building sequence-to-sequence models.
- `models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py`: >>   Neural translation sequence-to-sequence model.
- `models/rnn/translate/data_utils.py`: >>  Helper functions for preparing translation data.
- `models/rnn/translate/translate.py`: >>   Binary that trains and runs the translation model.

The Tensorflow `translate.py` file requires several files to be generated when using your own corpus to translate.

1. It needs to be aligned, meaning: `language line 1 in file 1.` <> `language line 1 file 2.` This
   allows the model to do encoding and decoding.
2. You want to make sure the Vocabulary have been generated from the dataset using this file:
   Check these steps:

`python translate.py
  --data_dir [your_data_directory] --train_dir [checkpoints_directory]
  --en_vocab_size=40000 --fr_vocab_size=40000`

Note! If the Vocab-size is lower, then change that value.

There is a longer discussion here [tensorflow/issues/600](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/600)

If all else fails, check out this [ByteNet](https://github.com/buriburisuri/ByteNet) implementation in Tensorflow which does translation task as well.